Disabling the minimize/maximize/close buttons in Microsoft Edge
I am writing a program in PowerShell that launches a new Microsoft Edge browser instance with a specific URL in the command line arguments.
The application needs to provide 5 features for the launched window: It can't be minimized, resized, closed, moved, or covered by another window.
To do this, I call the system32 .dll files. As a proof of concept, with notepad.exe, I got it to prevent minimizing, closing, and being covered. However, with Microsoft Edge, the only feature that works is Always-On-Top (can't be covered by another window). What I have found is that Microsoft Edge appears to have its objects set up/organized differently than other applications, including Microsoft Internet Explorer.
I know there are a few different dll functions to accomplish similar tasks. I have tried a few of them: EnableMenuItem, DeleteMenu, DestroyMenu...
Here is the my attempt at the code...
$function = Add-Type -MemberDefinition '
   [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
   [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
   [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern int GetSystemMenu(int hWnd, int bRevert);
   [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern int EnableMenuItem(int hMenu, int uIDEnableItem, int uEnable);
   [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern int GetWindowLong(int hWnd, int nIndex);
   [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern int SetWindowLong(int hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
   [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern int ShowWindow(int hWnd, int nCmdShow);
' -Name "User32Functions" -Namespace User32Functions -PassThru

$GWL_STYLE = -16
$MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x0000
$SC_CLOSE = 0xF060
$SC_MOVE = 0xF010
$SC_MINIMIZE = 0xF020
$SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xF030
$SWP_NOSIZE=0x0001
$SWP_NOMOVE=0x0002
$SWP_NOACTIVATE=0x0010
$SWP_SHOWWINDOW=0x0040
$WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000
$WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000
$WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000
$WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000

$process = Start-Process microsoft-edge:"https://www.google.com" -PassThru
#$process = Start-Process -FilePath notepad -PassThru

Start-Sleep 1

# Find the handle of the Microsoft Edge window
$hWnd = $process.MainWindowHandle
# Get the system menu of the window
$hMenu = $function::GetSystemMenu($hWnd, 0)

# Window is always on top
[Void]$function::SetWindowPos($hWnd, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, $SWP_NOSIZE -bor $SWP_NOMOVE -bor $SWP_NOACTIVATE -bor $SWP_SHOWWINDOW)

# Disable the close menu item (Alt+F4)
[Void]$function::EnableMenuItem($hMenu, $SC_CLOSE, $MF_BYCOMMAND)
# Disable the move menu item
[Void]$function::EnableMenuItem($hMenu, $SC_MOVE, $MF_BYCOMMAND)
# Disable the minimize menu item
[Void]$function::EnableMenuItem($hMenu, $SC_MINIMIZE, $MF_BYCOMMAND)
# Disable the maximize menu item
[Void]$function::EnableMenuItem($hMenu, $SC_MAXIMIZE, $MF_BYCOMMAND)

# Get the current window style
$style = $function::GetWindowLong($hWnd, $GWL_STYLE)
# Remove the system menu and minimize box from the window style
$style = $style -bxor ($WS_SYSMENU -bor $WS_MINIMIZEBOX -bor $WS_MAXIMIZEBOX)
# Set the modified window style
[Void]$function::SetWindowLong($hWnd, $GWL_STYLE, $style)

SetWindowPos keeps the window on top for both Edge and Notepad.
The bottom 3 lines remove the buttons entirely from view. I left in the notepad line as a comment if you want to see it working.
If you use the inspect.exe tool inside of Windows Kit you can see that Notepad (using this as an example because IE is no longer on my machine) has a "title bar" section containing objects for "Minimize", "Maximize", and "Close". Edge, on the other hand, does not have that "title bar" section and calls its sections "region". When you hover over the Edge window three buttons, inspect.exe will highlight what you pointed at and it goes to those "region" tabs.
I have also tried AutoHotKey, which is practically a wrapper for many dll functions. It had the same outcome. I am fine using PowerShell or AutoHotkey as a solution. As I said, there are many dll functions and different ways to accomplish the same goal and even portions working would be a step in the right direction. Thanks!
